# I have a problem that I can't locate data from html table to tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import bs4
from tkinter import *

def statno():
    covidTk = Tk()
    covidTk.title('Data statistics of COVID-19')
    
    lb1 = Label(covidTk,text='Country: ')
    lb1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

    lb2 = Label(covidTk,text=entcon.get())
    lb2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

    res = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find("table", {"id":"main_table_countries_today"})
    columns = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.find("thead").find_all("th")]

    rows = []

    for row in table.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
        rows.append([i.get_text(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("td")])


    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

    lb3 = Label(covidTk,text='Number of cases: ')
    lb3.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

    case_value = int(df.loc[lb2.cget('text')]['Total Cases'])
    lb4 = Label(covidTk,text=case_value)
    lb4.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
    
    

win = Tk()
win.title('COVID-19 tracker')

web = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus')
objSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(web.text,'lxml')

lbtitle = Label(win,text='Covid-19 Statistics')
lbtitle.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

lbcon = Label(win,text='Country: ')
lbcon.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=20)

conname = StringVar()
entcon = Entry(win,textvariable=conname)
entcon.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=20)

btncheck = Button(win,text='Check data',command=statno)
btncheck.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

lbcase = Label(win,text='Coronavirus Cases: ')
lbcase.grid(row=3,column=0)

total = objSoup.find_all('div',{'class':'maincounter-number'})
total_cases = total[0]
lbdat1 = Label(win,text=total_cases.text)
lbdat1.grid(row=3,column=1)

lbdeaths = Label(win,text='Deaths: ')
lbdeaths.grid(row=4,column=0)

total_deaths = total[1]
lbdat2 = Label(win,text=total_deaths.text)
lbdat2.grid(row=4,column=1)

lbcase = Label(win,text='Recovered: ')
lbcase.grid(row=5,column=0)

total_recover = total[2]
lbdat3 = Label(win,text=total_recover.text)
lbdat3.grid(row=5,column=1)




    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\Python Projects Fun\covid_gui.py", line 36, in statno
    case_value = int(df.loc[lb2.cget('text')]['Total Cases'])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1768, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1965, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 625, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3537, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 353, in get_loc
    return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'Brazil'
```

Sorry I have a problem that when I use `int(df.loc[lb2.cget('text')]['Total Cases'])` It shows the above error. May I ask what should I change if I want to locate the data corresponding to the country on the same row as tkinter label? I have searched the books thoroughly but still couldn't find a possible solution to solve the above error. So any people can teach me how to deal with it? I do not know why key error because I checked and no wrong spelling. For this problem, I already fixed by searching the documentations and learn more about the methods. Next time if I encounter the same problem, I could do it myself and think more then I think I can deal with it myself. Before I ask new ones, I will do more researches first and ask only when necessary.

Comment: Try changing `df.iloc[...][...]` to `df.loc[...][...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems.

Your columns or rows doesn't isn't the name of country.Also, the name of the column is wrong.To get the specific rows, you could use `case_value = df.loc[df["Country,Other"] == lb2.cget('text')]['TotalCases'].values[0]` to get the value directly.And in the end, you didn't use `mainloop`.There is no need to convert it to integer, you could use `Label(covidTk, text=case_value)` directly.

Now it works fine.

[image]

Comment: ```case_value = df.loc[df["Country,Other"] == lb2.cget('text')]['TotalCases'].values[0]``` I do not know why is [0] instead of [2] can you explain?

Comment: @DominicSham There is only one element(the result, only one "number").If you use [2] it will raise IndexError Exception.

Comment: Successful now Thanks very much